# Apply same override to all implementations of virtual method in base class

Tags: c#, virtual, abstract

I have an abstract class from a nuget package that's implemented ~30 different times in my C# project.  I'd like to avoid code duplication when implementing this class, if possible.
Let's assume I have the following abstract class (from a nuget package):

```
public abstract class Code
{
    protected Code(string type);
    public string Type { get; }
    public virtual string GetCodeString { get; }
}
```

I want to add a method that will take a value from my project's configuration file and use it in the getter function for the GetCodeString for every implementation of the abstract class.
Using a class like the following:

```
public static class CodeExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetCodeStringFromAppSettings(this Code code)
        => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CodeString"] ?? String.Empty;
}
```

I want to override the GetCodeString getter with GetCodeStringFromAppSettings() for every implementation of Code in my project.
To accomplish this it looks like I need to copy paste this extension method into each of the Code implementation.

Is there a way that I can override the Code class' virtual method prior to the various implementations?
Is there a better way to implement override a method's functionality when you don't have access to the base class?

Comment: For sharing the overriden functionality, implement a base class inbetween that calls the method. So your base class inherits from Code, your implementations inherit from your base class. For overriding a method's functionality when you don't have access to the base class, you can use the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public abstract class CodeSub : Code
{
        public override string GetCodeString => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CodeString"] ?? String.Empty;;
}
```

Inherit from your own abstract class.